# Does Tensorflow reuse intermediate results?

Tags: tensorflow

Given this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([3])
b = tf.constant([4])
c = tf.constant([5])

d = a + b
e = d - c
f = e*d

sess = tf.Session()
results = sess.run([d,e,f])
```

Would tensorflow recompute the variables 'e' and 'd' in order to compute 'f' or does tensorflow store the intermediate results of 'e' and 'd' in order to compute 'f'?

Answer (score 1):

Within a single `sess.run` TensorFlow will store the intermediate results and avoid duplicate calculations.

Comment: @AlexConfused I don't remember where I read it (probably the tf documentation). However, I have tested it myself on many occasions. You can easily test it by comparing the run times or by directly looking at the according graph in tensorboard.